# When is an extension a vector bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Let $ X $ be a smooth threefold and $ C \subset X $ be a smooth (but not necessarily irreducible) curve with ideal sheaf $ \mathcal{I_C} $. I am looking for an answer to the question of when an element $ \xi \in \text{Ext}^1(\mathcal{I}_C, \mathcal{O}_X) $ is represented by a short exact sequence with a vector bundle in the middle. More generally, for a rank $ 1 $ coherent sheaf $ \mathcal{F} $ on $ X $, when is an extension $ \xi \in \text{Ext}^1(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{O}_X) $ given by a vector bundle?

Here I'm not assuming anything about $ X $ but if you wish, take $ X $ to be proper/projective as I'm thinking of $ X $ as projective space in the examples I have.

Comment: Also, note that ${\cal I}_C$ is not a vector bundle. Indeed, if it were it would have rank $1$ (since it is isomorphic to ${\cal O}_X$ outside $C$). But then $C$ would locally be given by one equation, and this would contradict Krull's theorem (see Theorem I.11A in Hartshorne), because $C$ has codimension $2$. Hence the middle sheaf is never a vector bundle when ${\cal F}={\cal I}_C$.

Comment: @DamianRössler Really? For $A = k[x,y,z]$ and $I = (x,y)$ you get a short exact sequence $0 \to A \to A^2 \xrightarrow{\varphi} I \to 0$, but I don't think $I$ is locally free: locally it cannot be generated by a single element, so it's no line bundle. Hence it rank has to be $\geq 2$. But then $\varphi$ would have to be an isomorphism, because it is an epimorphism of bundles of the same rank.

Comment: @red_trumpet. I am referring to the situation described by the OP, where the right hand term in the exact sequence is the trivial sheaf.

Comment: @DamianRössler But the group $\operatorname{Ext}^1(I_C, \mathcal O_X)$ parametrizes extensions of the form $0 \to \mathcal O_X \to F \to I_C \to 0$!

Comment: @red_trumpet. Oops! You are right. I will amend my first comment. I don't think that there is an answer depending only on $\cal F$. It will depend on the arrows in the sequence.

Comment: The middle sheaf is given by a vector bundle if $\cal F$ is a vector bundle. This is because the middle sheaf is flat if $\cal F$ is flat. See eg Hartshorne, Prop. III.9.1A (e) and (f).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the natural homomorphism
$$
\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathcal{I}_C,\mathcal{O}_X) \to
H^0(X,\mathcal{Ext}^1(\mathcal{I}_C,\mathcal{O}_X)).
$$
Since $C \subset X$ is a local complete intersection of codimension 2, the sheaf $\mathcal{Ext}^1(\mathcal{I}_C,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a line bundle on $C$; moreover,
$$
\mathcal{Ext}^1(\mathcal{I}_C,\mathcal{O}_X) \cong \wedge^2 \mathcal{N}_{C/X},
$$
where $\mathcal{N}_{C/X}$ is the normal bundle of the curve. The extension is locally free if and only if the global section of $\wedge^2 \mathcal{N}_{C/X}$ corresponding to $\xi$ is nonzero at every point of $C$. In particular, a necessary condition is that the line bundle $\wedge^2 \mathcal{N}_{C/X}$ is trivial.

For the second question, the criterion is that $\mathcal{Ext}^i(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{O}_X) = 0$ for $i > 1$ and that $\mathcal{Ext}^1(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{O}_X)$ is generated by the global section corresponding to $\xi$.

Comment: I cannot, for the life of me, understand why the isomorphism of $ \mathcal{Ext}^1 $ restricted to $ C $ with $ \Lambda^2 $ of the normal bundle holds. Could you please explain what that isomorphism is? I also don't know the criteria for the second question, although it's very helpful to know.

Comment: Using $0 \to \mathcal{I}_C \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_C \to 0$ it is easy to identify this with $\mathcal{Ext}^2(\mathcal{O}_C,\mathcal{O}_X)$, and one has $$\mathcal{Ext}^i(\mathcal{O}_Z,\mathcal{O}_X) \cong \wedge^i \mathcal{N}_{Z/X}$$ for any local complete intersection. One way to prove this is by using local Koszul resolutions to obtain local isomorphisms, and then glue.